# How to setup multiple concurrent subscribers for a multicast channel?

Tags: distributed-system, aeron

[image]I am trying to explore the Aeron, I have a cluster of three nodes in my machine. What I am trying is setting up a simple model: one channel publisher in Node 1, and two channel subscriptions in Node 2, and Node 3.

Three of them are trying to communicate via multicast address as below:

- *Node 1: Broadcast to
  aeron:udp?endpoint=239.255.255.1:4300|interface=192.168.64.6|ttl=16*
- *Node 2: Starting Receive... channel:
  aeron:udp?endpoint=239.255.255.1:4300|interface=192.168.64.5|ttl=16*
- *Node 3: Starting Receive... channel:
  aeron:udp?endpoint=239.255.255.1:4300|interface=192.168.64.4|ttl=16*

I don't understand the result of attached image. Node 1 Publisher is trying to publish as fast as possible into the channel, unfortunately Node 2 and Node 3 are not consuming at the same time, there is only one consuming data at a time... In the screenshot below, node 2 always catchup the publisher, but Node 3 receive a few hundred of messages and then be hanged until Node 2 is completed 1 million of messages firstly. Are there any thing I missed?
However if I reduce the frequency of publisher to 1 message per second, for example, then I can see both subscribers Node 2 and Node 3 are receiving messages same time.

**The implementation of code:**
The publisher code: https://github.com/cseblog/aeron-demos/blob/main/aeron-multicast-ping-demo/src/main/java/org/multicast/Main.java

The Subscriber code: https://github.com/cseblog/aeron-demos/blob/main/aeron-multicast-pong-demo/src/main/java/org/multicast/Main.java

I am looking to understand this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably [flow control](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/wiki/Flow-And-Congestion-Control#flow-control).  The default flow control algorithm for multicast is `max` which will allow slow receivers to drop off.  If you want all receivers to see all data then you should try `min`.  You can configure this in a few ways:

[URL configuration](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/wiki/Channel-Configuration#flow-control-configuration):

```
channel: aeron:udp?endpoint=239.255.255.1:4300|interface=192.168.64.5|ttl=16|fc=min
```

[Media Driver Code configuration](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/wiki/Configuration-Options):

```
MediaDriver.Context ctx = new MediaDriver.Context()
    .multicastFlowControlSubscriber(new MinMulticastFlowControlSupplier())
```

Media Driver property configuration:

```
aeron.multicast.flow.control.strategy=min
```